# Oracle SQL: All rows greater than value (if value is present) OR all rows less than value (if value is not present)

Tags: sql, oracle, rows

I have a query, which returns me data in format:

```
ID      VALUE       INDEX
ID1     VALUE1      0
ID1     VALUE2      1
ID1     VALUE3      2
ID1     VALUE4      2
ID1     VALUE5      3
ID2     VALUE1      0
ID2     VALUE2      2
ID2     VALUE3      3
ID2     VALUE4      3
ID3     VALUE1      0
ID3     VALUE2      1
ID3     VALUE3      1
ID4     VALUE1      1
ID4     VALUE2      2
```

I need to find rows for which INDEX column, for specific ID, is greater than or equal to 2. If such rows are not present for particular ID, then only my query should return all rows for that ID having INDEX column less than 2.

e.g. in above data scenario, my query should return rows as:

```
ID      VALUE       INDEX
ID1     VALUE3      2
ID1     VALUE4      2
ID1     VALUE5      3
ID2     VALUE2      2
ID2     VALUE3      3
ID2     VALUE4      3
ID3     VALUE1      0
ID3     VALUE2      1
ID3     VALUE3      1
ID4     VALUE2      2
```

One way I can achieve is by executing same query twice. First query would return all rows where INDEX is greater than or equal to 2. In second query I will try to find all rows again where ID does not exists in IDs found in first query.

I do not want to execute same query twice. I was wondering if job can be done using single query. Please let me know if you have any idea on how to do it in single query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think window functions make this pretty simple:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(index) over (partition by id) as max_index
      from t
     ) t
where max_index < 2 or
      index >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for superquick feedback. As per initial test, it seems to be working. I will execute this query on whole table and share feedback at the earliest,